# iPad scroll to rotate div element

Tags: jquery, ios

We want to rotate a Div element using scroll on the Ipad, would love to get some pointers on where to start to achieve this, would be great if we could use the CSS3 transform to rotate the element, but using js or jQuery will suffice.

Cheers C

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/) shows how to implement div resizing and rotating using touch events.

The minimal peace of code from this tutorial to implement what you want is:

```
node.ongesturechange = function(e){
  var node = e.target;
  node.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + ((rotation + e.rotation) % 360) + "deg)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In brief:

- store evt.pageX/evt.pageY values ontouchstart
- calculate the difference while ontouchmove
- apply difference with -webkit-transform:rotate([difference]deg) translate3d(0px,0px,0px); to the div
- stop and reset values ontouchend

Usage of translate3d() is to activate hw-accelerating, it has no other purpose in this case.